# setImage() in ImageView in JavaFX what is the correct image parameter?

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I am trying to make a photo browser program using JavaFX and IntelliJ and have created an actionEvent for a button that should change the photos on click.

If I have the Image constructor as below with just a string file path it works fine (try #1), but when I try to use a combination of a directory and the file name stored in a string array (try #2) or a string array with the file paths (try #3) it doesn't work. When I tried printing the output of what I put in the Image constructors below, try #2 printed the text that is in the constructor for try #1 (/Thumbnails/IMG_0004.jpg) and try #3 printed the full file path for the image (/Users/Amrit/Google Drive/Computer Science/Mini IA/PhotoBrowser/src/Imported/IMG_0004.jpg)

**Try #1**

```
public void changeRight(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    image1.setImage(new Image("/Thumbnails/IMG_0004.jpg"));
}
```

**Try #2**

```
public void changeRight(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    image1.setImage(new Image("/Thumbnails/" + fileNameArray[3]));
}
```

**Try #3**

```
public void changeRight(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    image1.setImage(new Image(stringFilePathArray[3]));
}
```

this changeRight method is in a controller class which is linked to a cxml file called sample.fxml that I made using JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0. The directory all the images are stored in is within the project folder (PhotoBrowser): "/PhotoBrowser/src/Thumbnails/ImageName.jpg"

For all of them I was getting a null pointer exception and was not sure why or how to fix it.

Heres the code for the ImageView in the fxml file, its within the children of a GridPane:

```
<ImageView id="imgView1" fx:id="image1" fitHeight="195.0" fitWidth="300.0"    onMouseClicked="#imgClick" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true"    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1"   GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
     <image>
        <Image url="@../Thumbnails/IMG_0001.jpg" />
     </image></ImageView>
```

Comment: Do you get a NPE with your FXML code ? In which package is your controller ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question, but I also have to mention that you must have in mind that if your images are located inside your project (= later inside your jar) you won't be able to modify dynamically your thumbnails without rebuilding the entire jar.

Comment: I moved the files into the project folder and the code that allows me to read them into the controller class and it works fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. For your paths, use `file:Thumbnails/IMG_0004.jpg`.
Indeed, you have to use the **file:** prefix.